# When was the first form of footwear invented?

Tags: ancient-history

I am researching into the reasoning behind humans having toes, and as part of that need to know when footwear was first used. By this I mean when did humans begin to transition from bare-foot to "shoes"? When I say shoes, this could be anything from wearing leather strapped to the foot or multiple leaves tied together. Sorry for the short question but I don't know what else need be said.

Comment: This probably happened so long ago that no remains of this footwear could survive, and strictly speaking the question does not belong to history. As I understand, history begins with writing. Everything else is pre-history, and is studied by other sciences.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it deals with pre-history and a reasonable answer cannot be provided due to lack of records.

Comment: You can start your research [5500 years ago](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Areni-1_shoe) or 10000 years for [sandals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fort_Rock_Cave)

Comment: @Rajib Sorry to hear that this isn't suited for the [history site](http://history.stackexchange.com). I do, however, understand your perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From Introduction to History of Footwear](http://www.footwearhistory.com/):

> Spanish cave drawings from more than 15,000 years ago show humans with
>   animal skins or furs wrapped around their feet. The body of a
>   well-preserved “ice-man” nearly 5,000 years old wears leather foot
>   coverings stuffed with straw. Shoes, in some form or another, have
>   been around for a very long time.